# How do I spawn a new process that shares STDOUT channel (and nothing else) with the main one?

Tags: perl, spawn

I have a software that at some point waits for an output on a named pipe. This action is blocking and I would like to have a loading image in the meanwhile. I was thinking to accomplish this by forking the process just before the while loop begins.

```
my $pid = fork()

if (defined($pid) and $pid == 0) {
    show_animation();
    exit 0;
}

while ($return_line = $FIFO->getline) {
    # Process the output when it's ready
}
```

The `show_animation()` will check if the script that is writing the output is still running and will end as soon as it ends.

Unfortunately, this broke everything as the forked process shares with the main one the same socket and everything else. And [ZeroMQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ZeroMQ/lib/ZeroMQ.pm) seems to don't like this (programm aborted with a ZeroMQ error as soon as the process is forked).

I was looking for a module like [Proc::Spawn](http://search.cpan.org/~garrow/Proc-Spawn-1.03/Spawn.pm) that let me to share the STDOUT channel between the two process. Do you have any suggestion? Do you have any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Spawn a worker early on, before you create your sockets and stuff, maybe even before you load all your modules. Send a command to the worker where you currently create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, but I've found a solution that fits perfectly to my problem using threads:

```
use threads;

my $loading_threads = threads->create(\&loading_animation, $process_name);
$loading_threads->detach();
```

Putting this just before the while I didn't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

After `fork()` you can `close()` any filehandles you don't need any more.

```
use POSIX qw( close _SC_OPEN_MAX sysconf );
use constant OPEN_MAX_FD => eval { sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) } || 1024;

...

defined( my $kid = fork() ) or die "Cannot fork - $!";

if( $kid == 0 ) {
    # child
    $_ == 1 or close $_ for 0 .. OPEN_MAX_FD;

    ...
```